# ERR_DEVICE_LOCKED

Tags: ios, xcode

[native-run] ERR_DEVICE_LOCKED: Device still locked after 1 minute. Aborting.

Comment: sometimes it happed while device os version is grater than mac os version so check it.

Answer (score 0):

Unlock your device and try again.

**Note** that sometimes Xcode (or other IDEs) can not detect that you already unlocked your device and you should close and reopen the Xcode.

If it didn't work, try restarting your device too.

If not works, try to restart your Mac.

Believe me, these are still valid solutions for the billion-dollar company's products in 2021 ‍♂️